# Notepad++ Multi editing

Tags: notepad++

How can I have multiple cursors in Notepad++?

I will have a couple of tab delimited values . I need to write a query for all of these values. For example, if I get an Excel file with values like this:

```
1234 xyz pqr
2345 sdf kkk
...
```

I want to copy this whole piece of data into Notepad++ and write the query, inserting all the values at once.

Like this:

```
Insert into tbl (1234, xyz) where clm = 'pqr'
Insert into tbl (2345, sdf) where clm = 'kkk'
...
```

I used to do it with my previous text editor Ultraedit. Can this be done using Notepad++?

Answer (score 216):

Yes: simply press and hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, click and drag to select the lines whose columns you wish to edit, and begin typing.

You can also go to **Settings > Preferences...**, and in the **Editing** tab, turn on multi-editing, to enable selection of multiple separate regions or columns of text to edit at once.

It's much more intuitive, as you can see your edits live as you type.

Comment: 2013 here, v5.2: There is no (longer an) Editing tab or multi-editing option.

Comment: @BoltClock: Cool! Somewhere between version v5.2 and v6.2 that feature must have been added. Or maybe it got lost momentarily somewhere before that :)

Comment: @Wouter: Wait, I just realized how *old* v5.2 is... it's even older than this answer! I swear it was the latest and greatest at some point in time... how long have I been using this thing?!

Comment: A demo can be seen here: http://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/multi-editing.html. It looks like an old version, but I tried it in v6.4.5 and it worked fine.

Comment: This was something I just could not find out until now. I should point out that alt+up and down arrows also works from current cursor position. Now only question is can the arrow keys somehow be used to move multiple cursors like sublime text and chrome dev-tools

Comment: `alt+up/down` did not work for me. I had to use `alt+shift+up/down` instead. v6.9.1

Comment: Starting in v8.6, Multi-Editing is always on, and that option has been removed.

Answer (score 88):

In the position where you want to add text, do:

`Shift` + `Alt` + `down arrow`

and select the lines you want.  Then type.  The text you type is inserted on all of the lines you selected.

Comment: this is even better answer! remember to use shift+alt for any action like cut,copy!

Answer (score 87):

You can add/edit content on multiple lines by using control button. This is multi edit feature in Notepad++, we need to enable it from settings. Press and hold control, select places where you want to enter text, release control and start typing, this will update the text at all the places selected previously.

[image]

Refs: https://cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2015/12/03/notepad-multi-editing , https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/editing/#multi-editing

Answer (score 42):

> Notepad++ also handles multiple cursors now.

Go into Settings => Preferences => Editing and check "Enable" in "Multi editing settings"
Then, just use Ctrl+click to use multiple cursors.

**Feature demo on official website here** : https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/editing/

Comment: flawless answer2

Comment: Starting in v8.6, Multi-Editing is always on, and that option has been removed.

Answer (score 23):

You can use `Edit > Column Editor...` to insert text at the current and following lines. The shortcut is <kbd>Alt + C</kbd>.

Answer (score 10):

Notepad++ has a powerful regex engine, capable to search and replace patterns at will.

In your scenario:

1. Click the menu item Search\Replace...
2. Fill the 'Find what' field with the search pattern:

   ```
   ^(\d{4})\s+(\w{3})\s+(\w{3})$
   ```
3. Fill the replace pattern:

   ```
   Insert into tbl (\1, \2) where clm = \3
   ```
4. Click the `Replace All` button.

And that's it.

[image: NotePad++ replace window screenshot]

Comment: I've been using regex for these types of edits for 10+ years, but many people fix regex confusing or difficult to learn

Answer (score 6):

The easiest method to solve your problem (without going to a different editor or learning regex) is to record a macro.

- Place your cursor at the start of your text, click the 'record' button in the ribbon, and then edit just that one row of text.  You may only use arrow keys or ctrl+arrow keys to move around characters/words rather than clicking with your mouse.  The 'home' and 'end' keys are also useful.
- When you're finished with that one line, move your cursor (again without using the mouse) to the start of the next line.
- Click the 'stop recording' button.
- Click the 'play macro' button to check that it works on the next line as expected.
- Click the 'run macro multiple times' to do it again, and again, and again... :P

One advantage of this over 'multi-editing' cursors is you don't have to manually click and place cursors on every single row.  The second advantage is that you can work with tab-delimited data that doesn't have consistent size/length - just use ctrl+left/right to skip words.
Honestly, macros in N++ have saved about a year of my life.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Notepad++ only has column editing. This is not completely the same as multiple cursors.</strike>

Sublime Text has a marvelous implementation of this, might be worth checking out...
It's a relatively new editor (2011) that is gaining popularity quite fast:
http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=Notepad%2B%2B%2C%20Sublime%20Text&cmpt=q

Edit: Apparently somewhere around Notepad++ version 6.x multi-cursor editing got added, but there are still a few more advanced features for it in Sublime, like "select next occurrence".

Comment: the multi-cursor editing of npp is nowhere near as good as multiline editing of sublime.

Comment: Correction: the multi-cursor editing of npp is nowhere near as good as multiline editing of sublime by *default*. The scintilla library allows for all functionality that sublime supports. Any user can download a plugin such as nppscripts or pythonscript to access the underlying npp framework and map those scripts to keyboard shortcuts, emulating all sublime commands. For those who don't want to bother configuring their editor, by all means pay for sublime.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from but it isn't fair to ask a regular user to have to script the underlying editor framework for a normal feature. I'd agree with you if a plugin already did this (if I had more time I'd make one). Also this recent post http://sourceforge.net/p/scintilla/feature-requests/1085/ says "highlight next" might be easy to do, but you still can't have arrow key functionality. I wonder how easy "skip" would be to implement as well? Highlight next, skip next, and arrows can all be helpful at times.

Answer (score 1):

Original answer : https://superuser.com/a/1617635/1118822

Notepad++ don't has one option/shortcut to easily get multiple carets at the end of several lines. But you can do some of these tricks:

Remember you need to enable always the Multi-Editing on Settings/Preferences/Editing/Enable Multi-Editing checkbox.

You have 2 options:

**Option 1 - Without any extra plugin**

CTRL+click on each line (it doesn't matter in which part of the line you click) you want to add one caret to the end.
When you placed a cursor on each line you want to edit, press END key to move all carets to the end of the line they were placed.

**Option 2 - Using BetterMultiselection Plugin** (that's the solution !)

Install the BetterMultiSelection Plugin within the Plugins Admin window (on Plugins menu)
After the restart of Notepad++ you need to enable the BetterMultiSelection plugin on the plugins menu.
Do a column selection with ALT+mouse
Press END key.
Voila ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the plugin ConyEdit to do this.
With ConyEdit running in the background, follow these steps:

1. use the command line `cc.spc /\t/ a` to split the text into columns and store them in a two-dim array.
2. use the command `cc.p` to print, using the contents of the array.

Comment: You may be trying to be helpful but this is not what the OP asked. Sorry.