# Notepad++ mass rewrite highlighted numbers

Tags: javascript, notepad++

i am editing a javascript file in Notepad++. when i clicked on some number defined in an object (like `{something:244, somethingelse:244}` it highlihgted all the occurrences of the same number in the same file.

i thought, cool! but it turned out to be kind of useless, because i can't really do anything with it. if i want to edit them all at once i can't seem to find any option to actually edit the numbers that notepad highlights.

the only thing i have found about this issue online is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453151/notepad-multi-editing) but it seems to be dealing with something else

Comment: You can always try another editor: both Sublime Text (editor) and WebStorm/IntelliJ (IDE) have multiple cursor support, and are very pleasant to use.

Comment: Notepad++ on the other hand, is more of an ancient tool by now. And it hasn't aged well. Notepad++ was good like 10 years ago. It's time to upgrade ;)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but i use notepad++ for quick editing of small projects/one file (normally for large project i use either NetBeans or PHPStorm). i find sublime too slow compared to Notepad++

Comment: Notepad++ handles multiple cursors too (just enable it in settings/preferences)
But it seems the op just needs a _replace_ anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure I understand your needs, but how about:

- Double click on the number you want to edit
- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- in the `replace with` box, type the new number
- Click on <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Be sure to select "match whole word only" ( *or not, depending on what you want to replace!* )

Comment: possibly select "match whole word only"

Comment: nope, check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35292962/notepad-mass-rewrite-highlighted-numbers/35293210#comment58296525_35293206 seems notepad++ simply doesn't support it

Comment: @user151496: Sorry, I don't get you. Don't you want to replace for example `244` with `355` in the whole file?

Comment: if i had a number 4932024409, it would replace that too. imagine you want to update a position of something...

Comment: @user151496: Then, don't select  "match whole word only"

Comment: oh! wow, i stopped reading and dismissed find and replace option. now i see, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You'd use 'Replace...' (`Ctrl-H`) for that in Notepad++.

It sounds like you want it to edit in-place and unfortunately (AFAIK) the multi-editing of Notepad++ doesn't support this case in-place.

Answer (score 0):

This takes advantage of what I am intuiting you want to happen, so I'm not really sure if it's the answer you are seeking.

- Select the number of interest, which I presume to be 244.
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\W)244(\W)`
- Replace with: `${1}987${2}` if you wanted to change highlighted occurrences of 244 to 987
- Search Mode: `Regular Expression`
- Hit <kbd>Replace All</kbd>