# Replacing numbers with asterisks

Tags: notepad++

I want to replace multiple numbers with asterisks with Notepad++, how to?
Example:

```
109.169.76.0/22
109.169.88.0/21
109.190.0.0/16
109.196.166.0/23
109.196.172.0/24
109.196.175.0/24
109.200.30.0/23
109.200.192.0/21
109.200.208.0/20
109.201.133.22/32
109.201.133.24/32
202.55.45.41/32
```

should become:

```
109.169.***.***
109.169.***.***
109.190.***.***
109.196.***.***
109.196.***.***
109.196.***.***
109.200.***.***
109.200.***.***
109.200.***.***
109.201.***.***
109.201.***.***
202.55.***.***
```

(Sorry if I didn't describe it clearly, but I want to replace anything after "`NNN.NNN`" with "`***.***`" (N is number)
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\d+\.\d+/\d+$`
- Replace with: `***.***`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\d+         # 1 or more digits
\.          # a dot
\d+         # 1 or more digits
/           # a slash
\d+         # 1 or more digits
$           # end of line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this is not too long to edit and it has the same amount of characters per line, you can do this using [multiple cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453151/notepad-multi-editing).

If the data you have follows a predictable pattern, then you can use that to replace everything after a specific character. This is shown [here](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/notepad-plus-find-and-replace-text/#remove_text_after_a_char), alongside other helpful ways to edit or replace text.